# Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04, mysql5 causes upgrade hang

Tags: ubuntu, mysql5

I'm doing a release update from [10.04 to 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#From_10.04_to_12.04). The upgrade process walked me through all the conflicting .conf files and I chose to keep my version of mysql.conf. Despite that, the upgrade process is frozen. Here are the last few lines:

```
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/debian-start ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init/mysql.conf ...
```

[I've read](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1514195.html) that renaming mysql.conf to some backup name then continuing the upgrade works but I'm not sure how this affects my release upgrade. Anyone know what my next move should be?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! At 1am even.

I started a new ssh session and it showed 12.04 was running. Lots of packages needed updates so I ran the usual `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and there was a warning about resolvconf. dpkg was unhappy. Many a googling provided `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it was failing as well. Here's the saga:

```
josh@ccdev:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up resolvconf (1.63ubuntu16) ...
start: Unknown job: resolvconf
invoke-rc.d: initscript resolvconf, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing resolvconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resolvconf
```

I hunted down an existing resolvconf file and manually checked it over. It was identical to one that was working on a forum.

```
josh@ccdev:~$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Which is when I found `sudo initctl reload-configuration` [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/940762).

```
josh@ccdev:~$ sudo initctl reload-configuration
josh@ccdev:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up resolvconf (1.63ubuntu16) ...
resolvconf start/running
Processing triggers for resolvconf ...
```

Bam. Updates and upgrades worked fine. I also ran `sudo service mysql stop` just after starting the new session, just to be safe.